# Compiling RCurl from source on Windows

Tags: r, curl, compilation, windows-8.1, rcurl

As there is no Windows binary for `v1.95-4.3` yet, I need to install/compile the [`RCurl`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html) package from source on Windows 8.1. (64 bit).

Could someone tell me

1. Which version of [`cURL`](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) I need
2. Where the various files such as `libcurl.dll` etc. need to be placed exactly

Does the `x64` directory mentioned in the error message below correspond to the `x64` directory of the R installation?

```
> install.packages("RCurl", type="source")
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RCurl_1.95-4.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 879143 bytes (858 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 858 Kb

* installing *source* package 'RCurl' ...
** package 'RCurl' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Please set LIB_CURL
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: Q:/home
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/q/home
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
cp: cannot stat `/x64/ssl/bin/*.dll': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `/x64/bin/libcurl-4.dll': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `/x64/bin/libz.dll': No such file or directory
Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 1
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'RCurl'
* removing 'Q:/home/apps/rapptools/apps/r/R-3.1.1/library/RCurl'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"Q:/home/apps/RAPPTO~1/apps/r/R-31~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "Q:\home\apps\rapptools\apps\r\R-3.1.1\library" C:\Users\RAPPST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0MmGz8/downloaded_packages/RCurl_1.95-4.3.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the RCurl v1.95-4.3 binary file for Windows has been uploaded to CRAN as of this morning.  I was dealing with the exact same issue as you, and after building the binary file from source, all was well with my usage of RCurl again!

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html

```
install.packages("RCurl_1.95-4.3.zip", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the update and the kind words on github! Are you running on windows and managed to compile from source? It'd be very interested in the details with respect to libcurl etc.!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of cURL you have on your machine, but as it states on [this](http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/) website that version 7.37.0 seems to work for Windows 8

EDIT
You can try this manual download.  It specifies the .dll files you mentioned and is compatible with 64 bit
http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/2.15/

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to me simply installing or putting it somewhere on my machine won't really help as the package seems to be pretty rigid on where it looks for the DLLs. Also, I didn't find the files `libcurl-4.dll` and `libz.dll` in the bundle you mentioned. Any ideas?

Comment: @Rappster - Not sure if you tried v1.95-3, but it seems to be the latest binary I could find

Comment: Well, there are binaries until [v1.95.4.2](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/RCurl_1.95-4.2.zip), but that's not working for me (has to do with [this issue](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/532)). Thanks, though!