# Compiling older versions of RCurl from source on Windows OS

Tags: r, windows, curl, gcc, rcurl

I'm trying to revive the same question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023540/compiling-rcurl-from-source-on-windows).  I have searched for 3 days and tried every permutation that I can think of.

I have recently inherited an R project at work which has been deployed using R 3.3.2 and RCurl _1.95-4.8.  I would like to be able to deploy the project on Windows and Linux machines from source code and all is working well except for Windows deployment of RCurl.  I just cannot get this to compile but keep in mind I am no expert with Windows compilation so I'm hoping that I am missing something simple here.

My environment:

- Windows 10 x64 Pro
- [R 3.3.2](https://cran.r-project.org/)
- [RTools 3.3](https://cran.r-project.org/)
- [curl-7.59.0.zip](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html)
- [bitops_1.0-5.tar.gz](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/bitops/) (required by RCurl)
- [RCurl_1.95-4.8.tar.gz](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RCurl/)

My process:

- Install R (C:\TEMP\R\R-3.3.2)
- Install RTools (C:\TEMP\RTOOLS\Rtools)
- Update Makeconf in R (32/64) to reflect RTools installation folder

```
C:\TEMP\R\R-3.3.2\etc\i386\Makeconf
BINPREF ?= C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/

C:\TEMP\R\R-3.3.2\etc\x64\Makeconf
BINPREF ?= C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/
```

- Copy curl (\curl-7.59.0\include\curl) folder to C:\TEMP\R\R-3.3.2\include
- Run: R CMD INSTALL bitops_1.0-5.tar.gz
- Run: R CMD INSTALL RCurl_1.95-4.8.tar.gz

And am getting the following error messages:

```
    $ R CMD INSTALL RCurl_1.95-4.8.tar.gz
    * installing to library 'C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/library'
    * installing *source* package 'RCurl' ...
    ** package 'RCurl' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** libs

    *** arch - i386
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I/include -DHAVE_LIBIDN_FIELD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REQUEST_SIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_FILETIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRIVATE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HTTP_CONNECTCODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HTTPAUTH_AVAIL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PROXYAUTH_AVAIL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_OS_ERRNO=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_NUM_CONNECTS=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SSL_ENGINES=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_COOKIELIST=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_LASTSOCKET=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_FTP_ENTRY_PATH=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRIMARY_IP=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CERTINFO=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONDITION_UNMET=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_APPEND=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_KRBLEVEL=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_USE_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_HTTP_TRANSFER_DECODING=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NEW_FILE_PERMS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NEW_DIRECTORY_PERMS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_POSTREDIR=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXY_TRANSFER_MODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SEEKFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SEEKDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CRLFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_ISSUERCERT=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_ADDRESS_SCOPE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CERTINFO=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_USERNAME=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PASSWORD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXYUSERNAME=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXYPASSWORD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_MD5=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NOPROXY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_TFTP_BLKSIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_SERVICE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_NEC=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_SSL_CCC=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_COOKIELIST=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_FILEMETHOD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_LOCALPORT=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_LOCALPORTRANGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_NETWORK_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_TO_NETWORK_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_UTF8_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_ALTERNATIVE_TO_USER=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKOPTDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSL_SESSIONID_CACHE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_WRITEDATA=1 -DCURL_STATICLIB    -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c base64.c -o base64.o
    In file included from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/Rdefines.h:33:0,
                     from Rcurl.h:6,
                     from base64.c:1:
    C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/R_ext/RS.h:54:0: warning: "ERROR" redefined
     #define ERROR   ),error(R_problem_buf);}
     ^
    In file included from C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:71:0,
                     from C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/winsock2.h:23,
                     from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/curl/system.h:391,
                     from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/curl/curl.h:38,
                     from Rcurl.h:4,
                     from base64.c:1:
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/wingdi.h:75:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
     #define ERROR 0
     ^
    base64.c: In function 'R_base64_decode':
    base64.c:23:10: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type
         text = CHAR(STRING_ELT(r_text, 0));
              ^
    base64.c:44:22: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'Rf_mkString' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         r_ans = mkString(ans);
                          ^
    In file included from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/Rdefines.h:36:0,
                     from Rcurl.h:6,
                     from base64.c:1:
    C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/Rinternals.h:1351:7: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'unsigned char *'
     SEXP  Rf_mkString(const char *);
           ^
    base64.c: In function 'R_base64_encode':
    base64.c:65:10: warning: pointer targets in assignment differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         text = RAW(r_text);
              ^
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I/include -DHAVE_LIBIDN_FIELD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REQUEST_SIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_FILETIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRIVATE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HTTP_CONNECTCODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HTTPAUTH_AVAIL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PROXYAUTH_AVAIL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_OS_ERRNO=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_NUM_CONNECTS=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SSL_ENGINES=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_COOKIELIST=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_LASTSOCKET=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_FTP_ENTRY_PATH=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRIMARY_IP=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CERTINFO=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONDITION_UNMET=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_APPEND=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_KRBLEVEL=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_USE_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_HTTP_TRANSFER_DECODING=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NEW_FILE_PERMS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NEW_DIRECTORY_PERMS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_POSTREDIR=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXY_TRANSFER_MODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SEEKFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SEEKDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CRLFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_ISSUERCERT=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_ADDRESS_SCOPE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CERTINFO=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_USERNAME=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PASSWORD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXYUSERNAME=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXYPASSWORD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_MD5=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NOPROXY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_TFTP_BLKSIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_SERVICE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_NEC=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_SSL_CCC=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_COOKIELIST=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_FILEMETHOD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_LOCALPORT=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_LOCALPORTRANGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_NETWORK_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_TO_NETWORK_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_UTF8_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_ALTERNATIVE_TO_USER=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKOPTDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSL_SESSIONID_CACHE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_WRITEDATA=1 -DCURL_STATICLIB    -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c curl.c -o curl.o
    In file included from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/Rdefines.h:33:0,
                     from Rcurl.h:6,
                     from curl.c:1:
    C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/R_ext/RS.h:54:0: warning: "ERROR" redefined
     #define ERROR   ),error(R_problem_buf);}
     ^
    In file included from C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:71:0,
                     from C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/winsock2.h:23,
                     from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/curl/system.h:391,
                     from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/curl/curl.h:38,
                     from Rcurl.h:4,
                     from curl.c:1:
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/wingdi.h:75:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
     #define ERROR 0
     ^
    curl.c: In function 'R_curl_easy_setopt':
    curl.c:222:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
        buf->buf = RAW(el);
                 ^
    In file included from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/curl/curl.h:2761:0,
                     from Rcurl.h:4,
                     from curl.c:1:
    C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/curl/typecheck-gcc.h:56:9: warning: call to '_curl_easy_setopt_err_write_callback' declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_setopt expects a curl_write_callback argument for this option
             _curl_easy_setopt_err_write_callback();                               \
             ^
    curl.c:169:14: note: in expansion of macro 'curl_easy_setopt'
        status =  curl_easy_setopt(obj, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &R_curl_write_data);
                  ^
    C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/curl/typecheck-gcc.h:56:9: warning: call to '_curl_easy_setopt_err_write_callback' declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_setopt expects a curl_write_callback argument for this option
             _curl_easy_setopt_err_write_callback();                               \
             ^
    curl.c:171:14: note: in expansion of macro 'curl_easy_setopt'
        status =  curl_easy_setopt(obj, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, &R_curl_write_header_data);
                  ^
    C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/curl/typecheck-gcc.h:77:9: warning: call to '_curl_easy_setopt_err_debug_cb' declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_setopt expects a curl_debug_callback argument for this option
             _curl_easy_setopt_err_debug_cb();                                     \
             ^
    curl.c:179:14: note: in expansion of macro 'curl_easy_setopt'
        status =  curl_easy_setopt(obj, opt, &R_curl_debug_callback);
                  ^
    C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/curl/typecheck-gcc.h:56:9: warning: call to '_curl_easy_setopt_err_write_callback' declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_setopt expects a curl_write_callback argument for this option
             _curl_easy_setopt_err_write_callback();                               \
             ^
    curl.c:187:14: note: in expansion of macro 'curl_easy_setopt'
        status =  curl_easy_setopt(obj, opt, &R_curl_write_header_data);
                  ^
    C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/curl/typecheck-gcc.h:74:9: warning: call to '_curl_easy_setopt_err_progress_cb' declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_setopt expects a curl_progress_callback argument for this option
             _curl_easy_setopt_err_progress_cb();                                  \
             ^
    curl.c:194:14: note: in expansion of macro 'curl_easy_setopt'
        status =  curl_easy_setopt(obj, opt, &R_curl_progress_callback);
                  ^
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I/include -DHAVE_LIBIDN_FIELD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REQUEST_SIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_FILETIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRIVATE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HTTP_CONNECTCODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HTTPAUTH_AVAIL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PROXYAUTH_AVAIL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_OS_ERRNO=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_NUM_CONNECTS=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SSL_ENGINES=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_COOKIELIST=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_LASTSOCKET=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_FTP_ENTRY_PATH=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRIMARY_IP=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CERTINFO=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONDITION_UNMET=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_APPEND=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_KRBLEVEL=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_USE_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_HTTP_TRANSFER_DECODING=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NEW_FILE_PERMS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NEW_DIRECTORY_PERMS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_POSTREDIR=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXY_TRANSFER_MODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SEEKFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SEEKDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CRLFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_ISSUERCERT=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_ADDRESS_SCOPE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CERTINFO=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_USERNAME=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PASSWORD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXYUSERNAME=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXYPASSWORD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_MD5=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NOPROXY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_TFTP_BLKSIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_SERVICE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_NEC=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_SSL_CCC=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_COOKIELIST=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_FILEMETHOD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_LOCALPORT=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_LOCALPORTRANGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_NETWORK_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_TO_NETWORK_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_UTF8_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_ALTERNATIVE_TO_USER=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKOPTDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSL_SESSIONID_CACHE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_WRITEDATA=1 -DCURL_STATICLIB    -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c curlInit.c -o curlInit.o
    In file included from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/Rdefines.h:33:0,
                     from Rcurl.h:6,
                     from curlInit.c:2:
    C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/R_ext/RS.h:54:0: warning: "ERROR" redefined
     #define ERROR   ),error(R_problem_buf);}
     ^
    In file included from C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:71:0,
                     from C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/winsock2.h:23,
                     from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/curl/system.h:391,
                     from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/curl/curl.h:38,
                     from Rcurl.h:4,
                     from curlInit.c:2:
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/wingdi.h:75:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
     #define ERROR 0
     ^
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I/include -DHAVE_LIBIDN_FIELD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REQUEST_SIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_FILETIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRIVATE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HTTP_CONNECTCODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HTTPAUTH_AVAIL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PROXYAUTH_AVAIL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_OS_ERRNO=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_NUM_CONNECTS=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SSL_ENGINES=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_COOKIELIST=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_LASTSOCKET=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_FTP_ENTRY_PATH=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRIMARY_IP=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CERTINFO=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONDITION_UNMET=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_APPEND=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_KRBLEVEL=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_USE_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_HTTP_TRANSFER_DECODING=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NEW_FILE_PERMS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NEW_DIRECTORY_PERMS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_POSTREDIR=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXY_TRANSFER_MODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SEEKFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SEEKDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CRLFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_ISSUERCERT=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_ADDRESS_SCOPE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CERTINFO=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_USERNAME=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PASSWORD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXYUSERNAME=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXYPASSWORD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_MD5=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NOPROXY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_TFTP_BLKSIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_SERVICE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_NEC=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_SSL_CCC=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_COOKIELIST=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_FILEMETHOD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_LOCALPORT=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_LOCALPORTRANGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_NETWORK_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_TO_NETWORK_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_UTF8_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_ALTERNATIVE_TO_USER=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKOPTDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSL_SESSIONID_CACHE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_WRITEDATA=1 -DCURL_STATICLIB    -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c curl_base64.c -o curl_base64.o
    In file included from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/Rdefines.h:33:0,
                     from Rcurl.h:6,
                     from curl_base64.c:59:
    C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/R_ext/RS.h:54:0: warning: "ERROR" redefined
     #define ERROR   ),error(R_problem_buf);}
     ^
    In file included from C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:71:0,
                     from C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/winsock2.h:23,
                     from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/curl/system.h:391,
                     from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/curl/curl.h:38,
                     from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/curl/mprintf.h:27,
                     from curl_base64.c:49:
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/wingdi.h:75:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
     #define ERROR 0
     ^
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I/include -DHAVE_LIBIDN_FIELD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_MD5=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NOPROXY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_TFTP_BLKSIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_SERVICE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_NEC=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_SSL_CCC=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_COOKIELIST=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_FILEMETHOD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_LOCALPORT=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_LOCALPORTRANGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_NETWORK_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_TO_NETWORK_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_UTF8_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_ALTERNATIVE_TO_USER=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKOPTDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSL_SESSIONID_CACHE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_WRITEDATA=1 -DCURL_STATICLIB    -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c enums.c -o enums.o
    In file included from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/Rdefines.h:33:0,
                     from enums.c:2:
    C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/R_ext/RS.h:54:0: warning: "ERROR" redefined
     #define ERROR   ),error(R_problem_buf);}
     ^
    In file included from C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:71:0,
                     from C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/winsock2.h:23,
                     from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/curl/system.h:391,
                     from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/curl/curl.h:38,
                     from enums.c:1:
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/wingdi.h:75:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
     #define ERROR 0
     ^
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I/include -DHAVE_LIBIDN_FIELD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REQUEST_SIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_FILETIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_UPLOAD=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRIVATE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HTTP_CONNECTCODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_HTTPAUTH_AVAIL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PROXYAUTH_AVAIL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_OS_ERRNO=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_NUM_CONNECTS=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_SSL_ENGINES=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_COOKIELIST=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_LASTSOCKET=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_FTP_ENTRY_PATH=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_PRIMARY_IP=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CERTINFO=1 -DHAVE_CURLINFO_CONDITION_UNMET=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_APPEND=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_KRBLEVEL=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_USE_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_HTTP_TRANSFER_DECODING=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NEW_FILE_PERMS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NEW_DIRECTORY_PERMS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_POSTREDIR=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXY_TRANSFER_MODE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SEEKFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SEEKDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CRLFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_ISSUERCERT=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_ADDRESS_SCOPE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CERTINFO=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_USERNAME=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PASSWORD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXYUSERNAME=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROXYPASSWORD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_MD5=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_NOPROXY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_TFTP_BLKSIZE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_SERVICE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_NEC=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_SSL_CCC=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_COOKIELIST=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_FILEMETHOD=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_LOCALPORT=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_LOCALPORTRANGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_NETWORK_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_TO_NETWORK_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_UTF8_FUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_FTP_ALTERNATIVE_TO_USER=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SOCKOPTDATA=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_SSL_SESSIONID_CACHE=1 -DHAVE_CURLOPT_WRITEDATA=1 -DCURL_STATICLIB    -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c myUTF8.c -o myUTF8.o
    myUTF8.c: In function 'StringValue':
    myUTF8.c:284:26: warning: passing argument 1 of 'Rf_mkCharLenCE' from incompatible pointer type
         yylval = mkCharLenCE(wcs, wcnt, CE_UTF8); /* include terminator */
                              ^
    In file included from C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/Rdefines.h:36:0,
                     from myUTF8.c:3:
    C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/include/Rinternals.h:902:6: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'ucs_t *'
     SEXP Rf_mkCharLenCE(const char *, int, cetype_t);
          ^
    myUTF8.c:112:34: warning: variable 'use_wcs' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         Rboolean oct_or_hex = FALSE, use_wcs = FALSE;
                                      ^
    myUTF8.c:112:14: warning: variable 'oct_or_hex' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         Rboolean oct_or_hex = FALSE, use_wcs = FALSE;
                  ^
    myUTF8.c:101:14: warning: unused variable 'mbcslocale' [-Wunused-variable]
         Rboolean mbcslocale = TRUE;
                  ^
    myUTF8.c: At top level:
    myUTF8.c:17:12: warning: 'mbcs_get_next2' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
     static int mbcs_get_next2(int c, ucs_t *wc)
                ^
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o RCurl.dll tmp.def base64.o curl.o curlInit.o curl_base64.o enums.o json.o memoryManagement.o myUTF8.o -L/lib/i386 -lcurl -lrtmp -lssl -lssh2 -lcrypto -lgdi32 -lcrypt32 -lz -lws2_32 -lgdi32 -lcrypt32 -lwldap32 -lwinmm -lidn -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/i386 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/bin/i386 -lR
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcurl
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lrtmp
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lssl
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lssh2
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcrypto
    C:/TEMP/RTOOLS/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lidn
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    no DLL was created
    ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RCurl'
    * removing 'C:/TEMP/R/R-3.3.2/library/RCurl'
```

I am aware that using the latest Windows binary from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html) would work but I need to be able to install older versions of RCurl and other packages.  RCurl is the only one giving me problems now and it is due to the dependency on cURL during compilation.

There is obviously much I could learn from compiling libraries in Windows but hoping someone can help me get over this hump and help decipher what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance for reading this far.